# Probability integral transformation : Why doesn't this inverse affect inequality?

Tags: probability

I am reading this problem from DeGroot's "Probability & Statistics" 2nd edition.

[image]
[image]

I can't understand why $$\Pr[G^{-1}[F(X)]\leq z]=\Pr[F(X)\leq G(z)]$$, as nowhere is strict monotonicity assumed. I don't get why $G^{-1}[F(X)]\leq z\iff F(X)\leq G(z)$.

Comment: The inverse of a strictly increasing function is also strictly increasing!

Comment: Yes, but nowhere "strictly increasing" is assumed.

Comment: OK, but if the distribution function should be constant on some interval, there is zero probability on that interval, so can just be ignored!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, will you please elaborate that with answer? I will be obliged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that $G$ might not be strictly increasing, and thus the equivalence $G^{-1}[F(X)]\leq z\iff F(X)\leq G(z)$ cannot be deduced. However, it holds in the probabilistic sense the probability of one of these conditions being true and another false is 0.

Let us decompose the event $F(X)\leq G(z)$ into two cases depending on whether $G^{-1}[F(X)]\leq z$:
\begin{equation}
P( F(X) \leq G(z) ) = P\left([F(X)\leq G(z)] \cap [G^{-1}[F(X)]\leq z]\right) + P\left([F(X)\leq G(z)] \cap [G^{-1}[F(X)] > z] \right).
\end{equation}
Due to (not necessarily strict) monotonicity of $G$, we have $G^{-1}[F(X)]\leq z \Rightarrow F(X) \leq G(z)$. This implies that the first term of the decomposition is actually $P(G^{-1}[F(X)]\leq z)$. It remains to be shown that the second term is 0.

Note that by monotonicity of $G$, $F(X)<G(z)$ implies $G^{-1}[F(X)]\leq z$ and thus the event in question, $[F(X)\leq G(z)] \cap [G^{-1}[F(X)] > z]$,  is a subset of $F(X)=G(z)$. Hence,
\begin{equation}
P\left([F(X)\leq G(z)] \cap [G^{-1}[F(X)] > z] \right)\leq P(F(X)=G(z)).
\end{equation}
But, $X$ was assumed to have a continuous d.f., for which it was shown that $F(X) \sim U(0,1)$. In particular, the probability of $F(X)$ being equal to any particular value is 0. Thus, 
\begin{equation}
P\left([F(X)\leq G(z)] \cap [G^{-1}[F(X)] > z] \right) = 0.
\end{equation}
Substituting this into the second term of the first equation, we conclude that
\begin{equation}
P\left( F(X) \leq G(z) \right) = P\left(G^{-1}[F(X)]\leq z\right).
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir, for so elaborate and beautiful answer. Sir, if you will clear these following doubts, I will be obliged.

Comment: 1. How due to (not necessarily strict) monotonicity of $G$, we have $G^{-1}[F(X)]\leq z \Rightarrow F(X) \leq G(z)$? I know that for strict monotonicity that argument is correct. But, how does it follow for nonstrict case?

2. Why due to monotonicity of $G$, $F(X)<G(z)\implies G^{-1}[F(X)]\leq z$?

3. Why $G^{-1}[F(X)]\leq z$ implies that $[F(X)\leq G(z)] \cap [G^{-1}[F(X)] > z]$ is a subset of $F(X)=G(z)$?

4. How $F(X) \sim U(0,1)$?

Comment: OK, Sir, I got why $F(X) \sim U(0,1)$, it is just because probability integral transformation. Please just solve other three doubts, please!

Comment: For curious people and for my further reference, see [1.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15811487#15811487), [2.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15812085#15812085) and [3.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15811986#15811986) as well as [3.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814780/why-fx-leq-gz-bigcap-g-1fx-z-is-a-subset-of-fx-gz). These are answers from brilliant people.